# BASH Unexpected EOF

Tags: bash, eof

My Mac keeps telling my unexpected end of file for this bash script, on the last line. I am not new to programming but very new to BASH, does anyone see anything wrong with this?

```
#!/bin/bash  
#bootstrapper.sh
PIDD="$5"
while sleep 1; do kill -0 $PIDD || break; done
# Absolute path to this script. /home/user/bin/foo.sh
SCRIPT=$(readlink -f $0)
# Absolute path this script is in. /home/user/bin
SCRIPTPATH=`dirname $SCRIPT`
POSPAR1="$1" #-l
POSPAR2="$2" #location
POSPAR3="$3" #-d
POSPAR4="$4" #directory
cp -r -f $SCRIPTPATH/$4/* $2
rm -r -f $SCRIPTPATH/$4
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try simply adding a line break after the last `rm` line?

Comment: What arguments are you passing on the command line to this script?  That's what the $n terms are referencing, and I guess it's conceivable a missing or malformed $4 term would cause the problem.

Comment: That was my only suggestion as well. Some editors won't automatically do it, so make sure theres a blank line at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

I coped your code from the question on a Mac (copy'n'paste) and ran the file with:

```
bash -n -v x.sh
```

In fact, I did that twice; the first time, I ensured there was a newline at the end of the file, and the second time I ensured that there wasn't a newline.  And bash was quite happy both times.

This indicates to me that the problem is not in the visible characters; there are some invisible characters in the file causing grief.  You will probably need to scrutinize the file with a tool such as `od -c` to find the character that is causing the trouble.

Also, FWIW, the `readlink` command on my Mac gives:

```
$ readlink -f $0
readlink: illegal option -- f
usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]
$
```

The Linux version of `readlink` takes `-f`.  It isn't a POSIX command, so there is no *de jure* standard to refer to.

Comment: Did the file come from a Windows/DOS system?  If so, there might be carriage returns at the end of the lines (as well as the linefeeds unix systems like OS X expect).  Specifically, a CR at the end of the `while ... done` line could prevent bash from recognizing the `done`, so it keeps looking for the end of the loop until it runs into the end of the file...

Comment: @Gordon: I can confirm that if the file has DOS line endings, then you do indeed get the 'unexpected EOF' error.

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing the file with od -c revealed the line ending were \r\n, I did modify the file one Windows, silly me. Anyway, I am having another issues with the BASH script. This line:

```
while sleep 1; do kill -0 $PIDD || break; done
```

Is supposed to wait until the PID (stored in variable $PIDD) closes. It waits until it doesn't exist (the PID), but when it finally doesn't exist, it outputs: kill: 4: No such process. The rest of the script works as intended, but then the script doesn't terminate. Can I make the script terminate properly and not have that No such process be outputted?
Sorry for all the newbie questions, I'm awful at BASH and Linux.
Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: You should update your original question instead of ask another one on your answer. Try hitting the "edit" link and update your question there.